# Nhibernate Queryover with subquery get Next free number

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

How can I do this in nHibernate using queryover :

```sql
SELECT MIN(t.subid)+1 AS NextID 
FROM subject t  
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
    (SELECT id FROM subject n WHERE n.subid=t.subid+1)
```

Currently I have this but its not working because of this statement `"SubId+1"`

```
 _session.QueryOver(() => subject)
 .WithSubquery
 .WhereNotExists(
       subject 
       .Where(x => x.SubId==SubId+1)
       .Select(x => x.Id)
     )                                                         
 .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
                     .Add(Projections.Min<subject>(x => x.SubId)))
 .List().First()
```

Comment: Unfortunately Criteria/QueryOver don't really support arithmetic operators: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, using NOT IN instead of NOT EXISTS (results are the same) would be like this *(the SQL query would be a bit different, but result will be the same)*

```
Subjectsubject = null;
Subjectinner = null;
var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Subject>(() => inner)
    .Select(Projections.SqlProjection(
       // important the subid is the column name, not property name
       " subid - 1 as innerId" // the trick here is, that we compare 
       , new[] { "innerId" }       // inner ID - 1, with outer ID
       , new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 }))
    ;

var id = session.QueryOver(() => subject)
    .WithSubquery
      .WhereProperty(() => subject.ID)
      .NotIn(subquery)
    .Select(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Min<Subject>(s => s.ID)))
    .SingleOrDefault<int>();

var id = id + 1 ; // here we increment in C#, instead of projecting that into SQL
```

Summary: not sure about algorithm you've used, but the trick how to get "subid - 1" is to use projection:

```
Projections.SqlProjection(
       " subid - 1 as innerId" // sql statement 
       , new[] { "innerId" }   // its alias
       , new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 }) // type is int
```

*NOTE: I would expect the last Projections to be MAX*

Comment: Ok thanks . Ill give it a try and see if it returns want I need.

Comment: Yeah, let me know if anything. Also I fixed the wrong names (from my test example ;)

Comment: Hi it works :), my main goal its to get the next free id, like 1,2,3,5...10 the next free id will be 4 I know how to do it in T-Sql but using nHibernate is a bit different. It seems to work but Ill do more tests. thanks for the help .

Comment: Great :) enjoy NHibernate